# the MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped. Nothing worked so far

Tags: mysql, windows, service, mysql-8.0

I installed mySQL 5.7 and 8.0 on my pc, the first day it worked fine, but after a few days without using it, it just stopped working. The problem is I try to start the SQL server 8.0 in services in windows configuration and this warning appears.
[image: error message]
The mySQL 5.7 starts fine through services.
I have tried mysqld --install and mysqld --initialize.
When I run the second command this error appears:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --initialize
2023-03-07T18:28:35.102240Z 0 [Note] [MY-013847] [Server] Using jemalloc.dll for my_malloc and ut::malloc etc.
2023-03-07T18:28:35.117659Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2023-03-07T18:28:35.169045Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file 'C:\MySQLData\DESKTOP-KDETTU2.err' for error logging: Permission denied
2023-03-07T18:28:35.177600Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory C:/MySQLData/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2023-03-07T18:28:35.178022Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-07T18:28:35.178227Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue? I don't know what to do and I can't find nothing on the internet besides the mysqld --initialize solution.
edit 1: I have started the cmd as administrator but it doesn't work.

The question associated with my problem has nothing in common, I can't even start the mySQL server and that's my problem.

Comment: Pro Tip - If you are doing this in mysqld ... you are doing it the hard/longer way in a world where MySQL Workbench exists and is free to use ...
--> download here (nearly all main OS types)
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: A good example would be trying to do Spreadsheet work in MS Word .. its possible, but its more time intensive and ignores some of the tools that Excel has to assist you.   Some people like DBeaver and some others, but so far I've had great success with Workbench personally, hope this helps you.